# Challenge with vector: how to split a vector based on max/min conditions

Tags: vector, minmax

I've recently come across the following problem:

Let say I have an vector of random length (L) of 0 and 1 randomly distributed (for example [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]), I need to split the vector in two sub-vector at index K so following conditions are valid:

- the left sub-vector must contains the maximum number of elements from
  K in reverse order such as the number of zeros must be greater or
  equal to the number of 1s
- the right sub vector must contains the maximum number of element starting from K+1 such as the number of 1s must be greater or equal to the number of zeros

For example, [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] the split is at index 9, left vector is [1,0], right vector [0,1]

I wrote the following solution but the complexity is O(L^2). I think there could be a solution with complexity of worst case O(L) but I cannot find anything that can help me. Any idea? Thanks

```
var max = 0;
var kMax = -1;

var firstZeroFound = false;

for (var i = 0; i < testVector.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (!firstZeroFound)
    {
        if (testVector[i]) continue;
        firstZeroFound = true;
    }

    var maxZero = FindMax(testVector, i, -1, -1, false);
    if (maxZero == 0) continue;

    var maxOne = FindMax(testVector, i + 1, testVector.Length, 1, true);
    if (maxOne == 0) continue;

    if ((maxZero + maxOne) <= max)
        continue;

    max = maxOne + maxZero;
    kMax = i;

    if (max == testVector.Length)
        break;
}

Console.Write("The result is {0}", kMax); 

int FindMax(bool[] v, int start, int end, int increment, bool maximize)
{
    var max = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var i = start;

    while (i != end)
    {
        count++;

        if (v[i])
            sum++;

        if (maximize)
        {
            if (sum * 2 >= count)
                max = count;
        }
        else if (sum * 2 <= count)
        {
            max = count;
        }

        i += increment;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look at `rle`.

```
    y <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    z <- rle(y)
    d <- cbind(z$values, z$lengths)
        [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    9
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    1    1
[4,]    0    8
```

Basically, `rle` calculates the lengths of 0's and 1's at each level.
From here things may go easier for you.

Comment: I dont see how RLE can decrease the complexity